# python virtualenv install module error

Tags: python, paypal, debian, virtualenv

I'm trying to install paypalrestsdk to my virutalenv directory (/var/www/tipomat) through the command `pip install paypalrestsdk`.  The virtualenv directory is activated.

There is an error at the end of installation:

```
Command "/var/www/tipomat/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-JNYP2q/cffi/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-McjuwW-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /var/www/tipomat/include/site/python2.7" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-JNYP2q/cffi
```

I have setuptools(12.0.5)

This problem is on virtual private server with Debian OS.

Comment: Ouuu, I found solution: sudo apt-get install libffi-dev ..

Answer (score 1):

Hey this is Avi from PayPal. The issue is documented on the readme on github for [system requirements](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK#system-requirements).